# Error: Duplicate ID on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, duplicates

Im using radio buttons to gather a simple yes/no input on a form.

HTML code within the form:

```
<label for="sociable">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="sociable" id="sociable" value="1">
<label for="sociable">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="sociable" id="sociable" value="2" checked>
```

I'm using JavaScript to determine what the value is via the ID:

```
var userSociable = document.getElementsByName("sociable")
if (userSociable[0].checked) {
    userInput.push("1");
} else if (userSociable[1].checked) {
    userInput.push("2");
}
```

When I validate the code I get a duplicate ID error which I understand, and why it's happening, my question is, how do I work around this without changing the JavaScript? Having two different ID's for the same input seems illogical to me.

Comment: Duplicate Id is invalid markup, change the HTML to make the ID unique and then use `userInput.push(document.querySelector('[name="sociable"]:checked').value)`;

Comment: You cant define multiple ids of same name in a document

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 elements having the same ID under the DOM.

Comment: I'm aware of this, is there not a way to set an ID for a group of radio buttons rather than each individually?

Comment: Why don't you use class instead?

Comment: @user3574766 No, there is no way to set an ID for a group of radio buttons rather than each individually. Your idea of the two radio buttons being "the same input" is not true. They are two different inputs! Sure, they belong to the same group, which is marked with the `name`. And that's where Tushar's comment comes in.

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

thats why ,you have to use `class` here